# date_add gets Boolean instead of DateTime

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, php-7

I have a very strange error in my Symfony app and I don't know how to fix it. I want to set a `DateTime` in one of my entities with a `DateTime` after adding a special `DateInterval`. Here is my code:

```
$dateInterval = new \DateInterval('P1DT6H');
$snoozedTo = date_add($sickNote->getSickTo(), $dateInterval);
$channelUser->setSnoozedTo($snoozedTo);
$this->em->persist($channelUser);
```

In my UnitTests I get the following error:

```
date_add() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given
```

So I double check if `$sickNote->getSickTo()` really returns a `DateTime`. A `dump()` returns:

```
DateTime {#17791
  +"date": "2018-01-01 06:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

`get_class()` on the object returns `DateTime`.

Here is additional my getter method for the field:

```
/**
 * Get sickTo
 * @return Date
 */
public function getSickTo() {
    return $this->sickTo;
}
```

Why `date_add` gets a `Boolean` and not the `DateTime` object?

**Edit:** I also tried the objet method `DateTime::add()`. Same result.

**Edit²:** Here is my declaration of `sickTo`:

```
/**
 * @var datetime $sickTo
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
protected $sickTo;
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `sickTo` ?

Comment: I edited my question for this.

Comment: if you try `@var \DateTime` and `type="datetime"` ? (dont forget to update your db)

Comment: type = datetime as @SylvainAttoumani said?

Comment: Thanks guys. I have to change the type `type="datetime"` and the assertion to `@Assert\DateTime()`.

Comment: Mind if i put the answer so you can valid it ?

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `sickTo` is wrong. you declare it as a Date but you use a Datetime. Try to change that with something like that :

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime $sickTo
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */

protected $sickTo;
```